# Angular6 : why my parent method is not being called when notifying through child event

Tags: javascript, angular, components, parent

this is app.compoent.html

```
<app-regioncountry (notify)='doSomething($event)'></app-regioncountry>
```

this is country-dailog.html ( dialog box)

```
<ul *ngIf=isLoadCentral >
  <li class="list-unstyled" >
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (change)="selectAll();"/><span>Select All</span>
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let n of names " class="list-unstyled"> 
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{n.Id}}" [(ngModel)]="n.selected"  [name]="n.name" (change)="getCheckedItem();"   >
    {{n.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

this is region-country.html ( this is parent of dialog)

```
<div class= "row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col"> 
            <label for="rc">Region/Country</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" name="nameInput" mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()" class="btn btn-secondary"  >Select</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share enough code and description to trace the issue.

Comment: no where in this code is see a `this.notify.emit()`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to emit notify event as an example in select all method

`selectAll () {
  this.notify.emit(this.names);
}`